# how to find the most occurring sentence from a string data frame in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Name': ['Ann', 'Juh', 'Jeo', 'Sam'],
'Age': [43,29,42,59],
'Task1': ['drafting a letter', 'Sending', 'Pasting', 'Sending'],
'Task2': ['Sending', 'Packing', 'Sending', 'Pasting'],
'Task3': ['Packing', 'Letter Drafting', 'Packing', 'Letter Drafting']
})
```

In the above string data frame, I need to check the occurrence of the given conditions.

> condition = ["reading", "drafting a letter","packing book","sorting","sending","counting"]

for this I made a new column which combine Task1, Task2, Task3 using

```
df['NewTask'] = df[df.columns[2:]].apply(
lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
axis=1)
```

And I applied the logic obtained from

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sentence-that-contains-all-the-given-phrases/

and I am getting

```
Phrase1:count=0, plus the corresponding index values.
Phrase2:count=1 etc..
```

Now I need to find which is the most common 'occurring sentence' and most common 'occurring pairs of sentence' in df that is given in the condition. The above given data frame is a sample.

logic I worked on to get the count of each separately is

```
def getRes(sent, ph): 
sentHash = dict() 

# Loop for adding hased sentences to sentHash 
for s in range(1, len(sent)+1): 
    sentHash[s] = set(sent[s-1].split()) 

# For Each Phrase 
for p in range(0, len(ph)): 
    print("Phrase"+str(p + 1)+":") 

    # Get the list of Words 
    wordList = ph[p].split() 
    res = [] 

    # Then Check in every Sentence 
    for s in range(1, len(sentHash)+1): 
        wCount = len(wordList) 

        # Every word in the Phrase 
        for w in wordList: 
            if w in sentHash[s]: 
                wCount -= 1
                #wCount -= 1

        # If every word in phrase matches 
        if wCount == 0: 

        # add Sentence Index to result Array 
            res.append(s+1) 
    if(len(res) == 0): 
        print("NONE") 
    else: 
        print('% s' % ' '.join(map(str, res)))
def main(): 
sent = dff['NewTask']
condition = ["reading", "drafting a letter","Packing","pasting","Sending","counting"]
getRes(sent,condition) 


 main()`
```

Comment: `df.columns[3:]` returns `Task2, Task3` only. Also, please describe your logic directly in your question rather than leaving a link.

Answer (score 1):

To produce a count of rows by condition you can filter your dataframe to only contain the rows where one of your tasks meets the condition and then sum the rows.

```
condition2 = {}

for criteria in condition:
    condition2[criteria] = df.loc[(df['Task1'] == criteria) | (df['Task2'] == criteria) | (df['Task3'] == criteria)].shape[0]
```

if you would prefer to use your new column for this you can check the column for the task name though this is less robust.

```
condition2 = {}
for criteria in condition:
    condition2[criteria] = df.loc[df['NewTask'].str.contains(criteria)].shape[0]
```

in order to identify common pairs of tasks one apporach is to use the itertools module to create every possible combination of tasks then to count how many rows contain both tasks.

```
import itertools
combinations = itertools.combinations(condition, 2)
```

You can then find the rows where both of these tasks are carried out in the same way as before.

```
pairs = {}
for i in combinations:
    pairs[i] = df.loc[(df['NewTask'].str.contains(i[0]) )* (df['NewTask'].str.contains(i[1]) ) ].shape[0]
```

To return the highest pair you can use the below;

```
print(max(pairs, key=pairs.get), pairs[max(pairs, key=pairs.get)] )
```

Comment: Ryan, To avoid many conflicts, I have created a new column that will contain all 3 columns data separated with a comma. so I need to work on this new df-column and find the most occurring sentence which is given in the  'condition'. Also I need to find the most occurring pairs of sentences . the pair must be from the given condition.